# Source tree does not automatically commit successfull merges

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

There are no conflicts or working changes, everything I had was commited and I pulled to get everything from origin.

What used to happen is that source tree would do the automatic merge and commit it, so I would have my commit and the auto-merge-commit to push.

Now what happens is that the auto-merge-commit gets prepared, with the commit message and all, but I have to press the commit button. No conflicts or anything to resolve, just an unnecessary button push.

Is there a setting somwhere that I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

If you click the pull button, there is a dialog coming up with the checkbox "Commit merged changes immediately" (at least in Sourcetree on Mac. If you use another OS check for a similar dialog).

[image: Pull dialog]

Answer (score 0):

As told by dunni , you have to select that checkbox. You don't have to commit everytime you pull. But whenever you have working changes, you have to commit locally, pull the recent commits by others. Check for merge conflicts then push your code changes.